# Migrate gitlab to gogs

Tags: git, gitlab, gogs

Recently, i found a Gitlab alternative called [Gogs](http://gogs.io/).

Any suggestion for migrating repo in Gitlab to Gogs? I m not expecting all of it of course, just as much as possible.

Answer (score 16):

The correct steps for mirroring a repo is:

> $ git clone --mirror git@example.com/upstream-repository.git
>   $ cd upstream-repository.git
>   $ git push --mirror git@example.com/new-location.git

**Note:** Do not use `git push --mirror` if you did not clone the repo with `git clone --mirror`. Also, `git clone --mirror` is preferred over `git clone --bare` as it will clone all git notes and attributes as well.

Reference: http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/05/how-to-properly-mirror-a-git-repository/

Answer (score 10):

Clone localy the bare git repo (=server side repo)  and push it as a mirror to new repo:

```
git clone --bare http://my.gitlab.project.git
cd project.git
git push --mirror http://my.gogs.project.git
```

This will push all your commits, branches, tags etc. This will work for any git repo, whatever it's hosted on gitlab, gog, github, etc.

Comment: Take care! git push --all will NOT push tags! You have to add git push --follow-tags as well!

Comment: Yes good remarks ! That's why I've edited the answer with the clone --bare and the push --mirror